# Angular $http Interceptors for Auth Tokens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, dependency-injection

I'm trying to write a `$http` interceptor which will attach a header in order to authorize the application with a token.

I have an auth service which requests and stores the token for future use.

In the application config, I'm configuring `$httpProvider` and pushing a new interceptor onto the array.

The interceptor depends on my Auth service, in order to get hold of the token to send each time. In turn, the Auth service depends on `$http` in order to send the initial request to authenticate and retrieve the auth token.

I end up with a circular dependency graph that looks something like:

```
  $httpProvider
    ^      \  
   /        v  
$http  <-   Auth Service
```

Auth depends on $http, and through $httpProvider, $http depends on Auth.

Is there an elegant way to get around this? I thought about using an intermediate service, but ultimately, that would just be extending the dependency graph. Something needs to be fundamentally changed.

Is it possible to do something like `resolve` and reconfigure `$http` after the auth token has been retrieved?

Comment: You could just set the $http default headers, see the Setting HTTP Headers section [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: I want to control which API endpoints see the auth token. Doing it with interceptors allows me to control them within the request handler. I guess I could set default headers and then remove them in a HTTP interceptor which doesn't depend on Auth, but that seems kinda messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `$injector` to manually get a hold of your authentication service.

```
angular.module('app.services.authentication')
    .factory('AuthenticationHeaderInterceptor', ['$injector', AuthenticationHeaderInterceptor]);

function AuthenticationHeaderInterceptor ($injector) {
    var service = {
        request: addAuthenticationHeader
    };

    return service;

    function addAuthenticationHeader (config) {
        var token = null;

        // Need to manually retrieve dependencies with $injector.invoke
        // because Authentication depends on $http, which doesn't exist during the
        // configuration phase (when we are setting up interceptors).
        // Using $injector.invoke ensures that we are provided with the
        // dependencies after they have been created.
        $injector.invoke(['Authentication', function (Authentication) {
            token = Authentication.getAuthenticationHeaders();
        }]);

        if (token) {
            angular.extend(config.headers, token);
        }

        return config;
    }
}
```